# 'Button' object is not callable on second use

Tags: python, button, tkinter

So, this script is a text game that takes input from the player and outputs a story. I have been making a basic gui for it. One of the requirements is a save and replay option. I've run the script and it runs perfect...once. Once you hit the replay button it starts the gameplay function again and runs until the end where I get this error:

line 99, in text_output
    self.replay_button()

TypeError: 'Button' object is not callable

What has me stumped is that the script has already run over this line of code once without any error. I've tried grid.forget instead of destroying the button, but received the same error.

```
#some code that runs the gameplay
def text_output(self):
    self.T = Text(root, height=7, width=100)
    self.T.grid(column=1, row=5, pady=20)
    self.T.insert(END, contentSplit)
    self.entry.destroy()
    self.pull = ("Here's your story!")
    self.phrase_text.set(self.pull)
    self.replay_button()
    self.save_button()


def replay_button(self):
    self.replay_button = Button(root, text="Play Again", command=self.replay_game)
    self.replay_button.grid(column=0, row=6, sticky=W)


def save_button(self):
    self.save_button = Button(root, text="Save", command=self.save_story)
    self.save_button.grid(column=2, row=6, sticky=E)

def replay_game(self):
    self.save_button.destroy()
    self.replay_button.destroy()
    self.T.destroy()
    self.entry_box()
    self.entry.focus()
    self.game_play()
```

Comment: We need a testable example. This code is not testable. Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you put this line: `print(type(Button))` right before the problem line and show us the output after you click the button each time?

Comment: I actually just had a friend look it over and he pointed out the problem. I named the button the same name as the function it calls to. I changed the button name to self.replay_button1 and it fixed.

Comment: That will do it.